# how to force sort on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablerowsorter

I already have this:

```
TableRowSorter<FileTableModel> rs = new TableRowSorter<FileTableModel>(ftm);
    rs.setComparator(COL_NAME, new Comparator<DisplayFile>() {
            //<sorting code>
        }
    });
    setRowSorter(rs);
```

and it works. It sorts the rows as it should when the user clicks on the header.
I just can't figure out an easy way to sort the rows without the click on the header.
I want rows to already be sorted when they are displayed (user can then change asc/desc/etc. by clicking on column headers.)

How can i force the sorting? I know I could sort the rows in my TableModel, but i already have a working comparator, why not use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rowSorter.toggleSortOrder(colIndex);
```